# What to use as a file server with a web interface and user management on MAMP

Tags: file-sharing, mamp

I want to set up file/photo sharing for a largish group of friends and family. Flickr, Picasa etc. are not optimal solutions because setting up accounts, sharing albums and navigating privacy settings is going to be overwhelming for some of the people. I just want to be able to give people a URL, a username, and password and have it be easy peasy.

I want something very simple and easy to use (for the user) like [MyTunesRSS](http://www.codewave.de/products/mytunesrss/). I've looked at a complete "social" solution like Elgg but that feels like using a cadillac to kill a fly. I only need:

- User management
- Simple upload / download of files
- Plug-into-MAMP ease of setup is a bonus
- Search / metadata / tags / commenting not necessary but also earns bonus points
- Free / cheap licence

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**gallery**](http://gallery.menalto.com/) is a really good photo management software that is free.

Comment: That looks almost exactly like what I need, thanks!

Comment: Damns! I can't upvote you because I don't have enough rep :-).